# UV mapping vertices selected incorrectly

Tags: uv

I'm doing my first character and I have reached the part of the tutorial where you start to do the UV mapping, but I have some problems.
First, if I select the head or other part of the body with L, it will also select vertices from other parts. [image: vertices problem]
And second, if I activate the option to see the stretch and select a part of the body, blender will crash and I have to open again the file (While recording the video and some other attempts the file opens without problem, but some days ago the file crashed while trying to open it again and I have to use the back up that blender did.)
[Video where you can see how blender crashes](https://youtu.be/ficZDwg77rk)
[image]

Comment: It's normal that if you select a vertex that is at the border of the island it will also select a vertex on another island as it is the same vertex on the mesh. As for the crash it doesn't happen on my computer with Blender 3.2

Comment: If you don't want the border vertices to be selected on other UV islands than the ones you actually wanted to select, switch the _Select Mode_ to _Face_ instead of _Vertex_ (just like in _Edit Mode_).